# How to get user information like email, name using "user" param in Sign in with apple feature?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

Apple introduced Sign in with apple feature in iOS 13 and later iOS at WWDC19. I have implemented that feature in my application.

When the user authenticates the first time for an app, We will get the authentication information like Email, Name, User, State etc in the below delegate method.

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) { }
```

Once the user successfully authenticated, Apple will maintain the app information in iCloud under Apple Sign in.

Again when the user tries to authenticate for the same app, Apple will return User, State etc. It should not return the name and email information.

Is there any way to get the user's email and name using that user param in the above delegate method.

Comment: Please see my answer and mark it as accepted as i have provided the link now

Comment: Do you get same value for `id_token` ? If yes, you can retrieve the stored info from your db using that

Comment: @iOSDev I can get the "user" param same at every time. I can use that to store locally. but I don't want to do that. I need that information by authenticating apple sign-in on next time.

Comment: Any solution to identify email /Apple ID please help. I am getting in to same issue I need Apple ID to check in my database whether the user have id existing for open auth.

Answer (score 8):

As per Apple documentation, you cannot get the name or email again by doing the same auth process again on the same or any other device unless the user stops using Sign in with Apple for your app and later reconnects to your app. Even then you will only get it for the very first time.

Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple#3383768)

Comment: What a terrible system. Thanks for the headaches, Apple. And also, thanks for FORCING me to use it... Google Sign in works just fine... :-(

Answer (score 5):

Sign in with Apple does not return email and name when you are trying to auth the same app again.

However, you get a user id(token) which you can use to verify the login for next time.

For Name and Email you can store those credentials on your database using an api and can fetch and authenticate again whenever same user with same token do login again.

See the answer here from **Dima_Beliy**, who is an Apple employee:

> The scopes are only shared once, during the initial authorization.   Once the SIWA API returns the information, it is up to the client application to store it within their systems.   For follow up authorizations, the "user" identifier returned as part of SIWA API should be used as a means of fetching the previously shared information from your system.
>
> Once SWIA API returns the information, the application should create an account in its own system, store the information and later use the "user" identifier to retrieve it for follow on authorizations.
>
> The data is only returned once for privacy reasons, we do not support an ongoing data sharing.
>
> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119826

Comment: Can I have the link for bug report link in the apple forums?

Comment: @VimalkumarN.M. Yes wait a minute , Let me send you.

Comment: It's not a bug. This condition is documented in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple#3383768)